# Using PHP how can i display images which have been saved in SQL as a image path

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve images from my SQL database which have been saved using the image path. The images are saved on the server. When i retrieve the images , nothing is returned.

```
if(isset($_GET))
{
  include_once "mysql_connect.php"; 
  $text = $_GET['text']; 


  if($text=="")
  {

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `URL` FROM `gallery` WHERE `img_text` LIKE '1'")
  or die(mysql_error());  

  while( $rows=mysql_fetch_array($query) )
  {
   $search[] = $rows[0];

  }

 $result = array();
 $result["result"] = 500;
 $result["message"] = "Database Read Successfully";
 $result["rows"] = $search;
 echo json_encode($result);
 exit;
```

The example of code is for a search without the user entering a value. Within the SQL statement 'URL' is the field where the image paths are stored.The images paths values are the complete URL http://example.com/images/test.jpg and stored as a VARCHAR(200) . Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to display the URL or the raw image?

Comment: What's the expected result from code you've given? Simply taking $row['URL'] from the while loop will give you the URL, but still I don't understand how the logic below the loop is relevant to taking img path? Also what's the 0 row (first) of the query you've defined as example?

Comment: You sure condition `WHERE img_text LIKE '1'` get satisfied ?

Comment: Royal Bg - The logic below the loop is the parameters the app is expecting, the 0 in rows can probably be removed.

Comment: Rikesh yes it gets satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not work well. You are not closing the `if` statement.

Also, when `$text` is not empty you don't have any query to the database...

You would need something like:

```
if($text==""){
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `URL` FROM `gallery` WHERE `img_text` LIKE '1'")
  or die(mysql_error());  
}

//when $text is not empty...
else{
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `URL` FROM `gallery` WHERE `img_text` LIKE '".$text."'")
  or die(mysql_error());  
}

while( $rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $search[] = $rows[0];
}
```

By the way, try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_query`, this last one is obsolete and is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: The if statements are being closed this was a section of code also there is else statement which catches if there is a value for $test.

Answer (score 0):

The images are in the server, so the path only works there.

If you do a:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

I guess you are returning this info to the client, the images path have no value there if you want to display them!

If you want to show the user the image you need to use a HTML `img` tag and fill the src attribute with the path **FROM THE SERVER**.

Comment: Thanks Nary , however i am passing the full URL which should work , this is for a mobile app (iphone) .

Comment: hmm I see, what do you get as JSON response? or you just get nothing at all?